# How to restrict to React.Fragment of certain children types?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a component that I have typed with flow, and it only allows certain types of elements, a very restricted list.

Now I need to expand it to also accept a `Fragment` so we are able to do some render logic and group children. However, I only want to take Fragments containing an specific subset of valid components, just like the normal type.

So this is what I have now:

```js
type ValidChilds =
  | item
  | header
  | separator

type PropsA = {
  className?: string,
  children: ChildrenArray<Element<ValidChilds>>
}
```

As I said, this works very nice to restrict the children.
So what I want now, is to be able to accept this:

```
<>
<item>
<header>
</>
```

but not this:

```
<>
<other>
</>
```

I tried this, but it is not working:

```js
type ValidChilds =
  | item
  | header
  | separator
  | AbstractComponent<{ children: ValidChilds }, typeof React.Fragment>

type PropsA = {
  children: ChildrenArray<Element<ValidChilds>>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the [`React.Fragment` definitions](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/a4dd93b3ca2e635fb8e5c9cbf30a48f590d88776/lib/react.js#L238), I [gave it a try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBdkwBDAZzACUBTUgY2KnzizAHJ87H30oBXAHaMMcQWABicOAAoAlGADeqMGC6F++cQB4AJhgBuYYAD5UAXz5CRYsACFS+eUpVqaGrWD2HjZy6kIATxwaMAA1UhgMXQBRGBosGkFCSgBeMFcAH2puQgA6OISkwm0gkLgoSWkzVWzaBnzCxOTS4JoK+0casGyZRTB6AAsMGF0uQQB+AC5wyOim4vIAGjA8tbBzBVSTHIa8gDk4XRp0MtCABRYcNKVM1yGRsaSZ+sY8gGFh0fGAQXx8UiBbQRKKxeLNFJmTL+ATCQiicQAFRo5EIMhwV3IM0ucGuCmUqnUmh0+iMpgs6G0NUUoDAAGVBnB+KMwDgKJQUJYvMjUd0vFI4L5XF4HPghV5gDzCGYVNopXyqcLVNoBeLVMrRWqJTVtJKUdL0KoaeAGUyWTR-gRkMAudz9XyvDg1br5Ya7bylYr1ertE7yd7dd0XfbUIGgA), but it looks like it's not possible currently, as we can't override the [core Fragment statement definitions](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/a4dd93b3ca2e635fb8e5c9cbf30a48f590d88776/src/typing/statement.ml#L5896).

Might be worst opening an issue as it's definitely a useful case.

Comment: That was my guess, but I wanted to get it sure first. Thbaks